# General rules for transforming boolean equations?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Are there general or restricted rules for transforming between equivalent boolean equations?

A concrete problem that I have is given the following equation:

```
p -> (r <-> q) = True
```

Is it possible to transform it to an equation with `r` on the left and no `r` on the right? Something like this:

```
r = f(p, q)
```

I expanded `->` and `<->` to just `or` and `and`, then multiply both sides by `p`, but got stuck:

```
~p \/ (rq \/ ~r~q) = True
rpq \/ ~rp~q = p
```